# Show that $K[X^3,X^{11}]$ is a noetherian domain. Is my proof correct?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, noetherian

Q: Let K be a field and let $A=K[X^3,X^{11}]\subset K[X]$. Show that A is an Noetherian Domain.

My proof:

$[X^3,X^{11}] \simeq K[X,Y]/(x^{11}-y^3)$

K is a field so K is noetherian. From Hilbert's base theorem we get K[X] is also noetherian and, by using it again, (K[X])[Y]=K[X,Y] is noetherian as well.

$x^{11}-y^3$ is a polynomial of degree 3 over K[X] with no roots in K[X], thus it is irreducible over K[X]. Therefore $x^{11}-y^3$ is irreducible over K[X,Y].
This implies that $(x^{11}-y^{3}$ is a prime and finitely generated (1) ideal in K[X,Y] and such $K[X,Y]/(x^{11}-y^3)$ is both a domain and is noetherian.

PS: now trying to figure out how I can find A's Krull Dimension from here; could use a hint

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal for Krull dimension, beyond the bare definition?

Comment: I don't have any, but if you can recommend some that would be helpful here, I'll look them up.

Comment: Gosh, I just googled “Krull dimension” and found a list of properties that contains several that you can use. Of course the proofs that these are valid are not there. So it depends on what you’re willing to use without seeing a proof thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ring is a subring of a domain, so it is clearly a domain. Your ring is manifestly finitely generated over a field, so it is noetherian. There is no need to have an explicit description of the ring to conclude these things.

On the other hand, since your ring $A$ is contained in $K[X]$, its fraction field $F$ is contained in the fraction field of $K[X]$, which is the field of rational functions $K(X)$. Since $X^3$ and $X^{11}$ are in $A$ and $X=(X^3)^4/X^{11}$ is an element of $F$, we see that in fact $F=K(X)$.

Now the Krull dimension of a domain which is an algebra over a field $K$ is equal to the transcendence degree of its fraction field over $K$, so we see at once that $\dim A=1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$K[X,Y]/(X^{11}-Y^3)$ is an integral extension of $K[X]$, hence it has the same Krull dimension by the *Going up theorem*.

Comment: If $A=K[X,Y]/(X^{11}-Y^3)\simeq K[X^3,X^{11}] \subseteq K[X]$, can A be an extension of K[X]?

Comment: It is isomorphic to $K[T^3,T^{11}]$, where $T$ is another indeterminate.